# I segue from two viewControllers to one viewController. How to unwind segue to the caller?

Tags: swift, segue

[image: segue screenshot]

Screenshot above is 2 segue; from (view1 or view2) to view3

When creating the unwind segue, how do I get it to call the right @IBAction method?

```
    // code in view1.swift
    @IBAction func backview1(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }

    // code in view2.swift
    @IBAction func backview2(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }
```

Should I add code in view3.swift?
How do I code the back segue method in view3.swift in order to go back to origin view?

Comment: edit and link image...
and then how show image directly?

Comment: I added an `!` before your image reference to show it inline.

Comment: thanks for your usefull tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a segue you can do it by CTRL clicking on an UI element, for instance, a UIButton to the destination UIViewController:

[image: segue]

Then on both of your source UIViewController that you want to go back to from and unwind segue you need to implement the following method:

```
 @IBAction func unwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

After doing this you can again CTRL drag to perform an unwind segue:

[image: unwind]

Answer (score 1):

If you name the function you are returning to the same in both viewControllers, then you will be returned to the one that called `VC3`.

For example, put this in both VC1 and VC2:

```
@IBAction func backFromVC3(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Then, when you create your unwind segue, just choose `backFromVC3` from the pop-up.

Comment: huk!! resolve my problem for your advice...
...
thank you ...^^''